# Incorporar adapterview a un listview llenado desde base de datos

Tags: android, listview

El caso es que ahora mismo lleno correctamente el `listview` con la información que tengo en la base de datos. Pero quiero hacerlo personalizado por medio de los adaptadores como he hecho otras veces para listas personalizadas.

El problema es que no sé integrar los adapters al código que he incluido a continuación. Si pudierais ayudarme os lo agradecería mucho.

```
public class registroNotas extends Activity {

    ListView lstCursos;
    String recuperado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_registro_notas);

        //Recuperamos el código del logeo, que lo vamos a utilizar para mucha cosas
        Bundle recupera = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(recupera != null){
            recuperado = recupera.getString("cod");
        }

        Thread tr2 = new Thread (){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                final String resultado = enviarGET (recuperado);
                runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ////////////////////////////////////////
                        cargarListView (ArregloLista(resultado));
                        //ArregloLista ( resultado );
                        ////////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        tr2.start ();
    }

    public String enviarGET(String id){

        URL url = null;
        String linea = "";
        int respuesta = 0;
        StringBuilder resul = null;

        try {
            //url = new URL ("");
            url = new URL ("");
            //Ahora enviamos el dato
            HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
            //Guardamos la respuesta en el entero, porque sera un uno o un cero
            //Esto es lo que devuelve la BD una vez hacemos la consulta
            respuesta = conection.getResponseCode ();
            //Inicializamos resul
            resul = new StringBuilder ();

            if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream (conection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (in));

                while ((linea = reader.readLine ()) != null){
                    resul.append (linea);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return resul.toString ();
    }

    public void mostrar(String response) {
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray (response);
            for(int i=0;i<json.length ();i++){
                //Aquí llenamos un textView en el caso de tenerlo del siguiente modo:
                //nombre_TextView.setText("Alumno: "+json.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombreAlu"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    //Metodo que permite crear un arraylista para llena el listview
    public ArrayList<String> ArregloLista(String response){
        ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String> ();
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray (response);
            String texto = "";
            String texto2 = "";
            for(int i=0;i<json.length ();i++){
                texto = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("titulo");
                texto2 = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion");
                listado.add(texto + "\n" +texto2);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return listado;
    }
    //Aquí es donde va TODA LA CHICHA
    public void cargarListView(ArrayList<String> datos){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        lstCursos = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listCursos);
        lstCursos.setAdapter (adaptador);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

podés crear un archivo ejemplo: post.xml en layout
y después agregar lo siguiente en el getView( del adapter

```
listItemView = null == convertView ? layoutInflater.inflate(
R.layout.post, parent, false) : convertView;
```

donde el R.layout.post  es el nombre del xml

Post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagenPost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textoTitulo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenPost"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

El trabajo lo esta realizando tu código, despues de recibir una respuesta se parsea mediante este método:

```
  public ArrayList<String> ArregloLista(String response){
```

y el método `cargarListView()` se encarga de llenar los datos en el `Adapter` y asignar el adapter a tu `ListView` (`lstCursos`):

```
 public void cargarListView(ArrayList<String> datos){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        lstCursos = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listCursos);
        lstCursos.setAdapter (adaptador);
    }
```

Aquí el problema es verificar que en realidad estas obteniendo resultados al realizar la petición:

```
 final String resultado = enviarGET (recuperado);
```

Comment: Sí si, claro, cuando realizo la petición sí que obtengo los datos y lleno la lista con Titulo y descripción en cada caso. El problema que tengo es que no sé como personalizar esa lista para poder cambiar la fuente, color de la letra, etc. Además, ya tengo implementadas las clases registroAdapter y registroUser, que son las que empleo para personalizar la lista. De la consulta yo obtengo texto y texto2, que son con los que lleno el listview de toda la vida.